# Active_admin undefined method 'patch'. Conflict with routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, activeadmin, roles

I am using ruby-2.1.1, gem [the_role](https://github.com/the-teacher/the_role) and [active_admin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin)

When I am trying to install active_admin, using

```
rails generate active_admin:install
```

I have got the following error:

```
.../config/routes.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined 
method `patch' for ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x000000073516d0 (NoMethodError)
```

here is code in my routes.rb

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1) do
      resources :leads
    end
    scope module: :v2, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 2, default: true) do
      resources :leads
      patch '/leads/update' => 'leads_controller#update', as: 'update_leads'
    end
  end
```

If i replace patch => put, I have got another error, in gem [the_role](https://github.com/the-teacher/the_role):

```
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/the_role-2.3/config/routes.rb:4:in `block (3 levels) 
in <top (required)>': undefined method `patch' 
for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x0000000850e990> (NoMethodError)
```

How can I install Active_admin?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you try use `match` instead `put` or `patch`?

Comment: something like `match '/leads/update', to: 'leads_controller#update', via: :patch`, because `ActionDispatch::Routing` have no method like `patch` or `put` or 'get'.

Comment: before I try to install active_admin all routes worked just fine. I have found out, that active admin requires actionpack (~> 3.0.0.rc2), when my actionpack (4.0.3). I think the problem related to this dependency

Comment: If it's a dependency issue, try using `gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'`.

Comment: Thank you, Josh. There was a dependency issue, please post your comment as answer and I mark it as correct